# GLKVIew Without GLKViewController

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I am trying to lay a 3D object in front of the camera view in iPhone. For the camera view I am using `AVFoundation`. I tried to create a `GLKView` and added it as a subview to the view displaying the camera view. Now the problem I am facing is how to call `update` function. Do I call `drawInRect` manually to redraw the object every time ?. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never call the drawInRect yourself unless you really know what you are doing.

Set a timer (can be a CADisplayLink type) and call the glkview display method:

```
[self.drawingSpace display];
```